# Script isn't removing all color attributes

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a script for blender that will remove all color attributes from a mesh.

This is what I've got:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

for obj in scene.objects:    
    print("Checking to see if " + obj.name + " has any vertex colours.")
    if obj.data.color_attributes:
        
        print("It does!  I guess I'll delete them")
        for attr in obj.data.color_attributes:
            print("removing " + attr.name + " ...")
            obj.data.color_attributes.remove(attr)
            
    else:
        print("It doesn't!")
```

This appears to work fine, but if the mesh has three or more color attributes it doesn't remove all of them.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same result as you. I don't know why, I guess it's a matter of order.

But this works fine, it successfully removes it from last to first.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type != "MESH": continue
    print("Checking to see if " + obj.name + " has any vertex colours.")
    if obj.data.color_attributes:
        
        attrs = obj.data.color_attributes
        for r in range(len(obj.data.color_attributes)-1, -1, -1):
            attrs.remove(attrs[r])
```

Comment: The reason it works is because in the OP they're deleting items of the list while iterating over it. Here you're using the item indices, beginning with the last one and ending with the first one, so when you delete an item the subsequent indices are still the same ,whereas when you iterate over the indices in order (0, 1, ... n) and you delete an item, the subsequent indices are all shifted by -1. so every time you delete an item, you miss the next one. Another solution : `while obj.data.color_attributes: obj.data.color_attributes.remove(obj.data.color_attributes[0])`